# how to dual boot with bootx64.efi

Tags: dual-boot, grub, uefi, boot-loader

**My device:**

Thinkpad X1 Carbon and with Windows 11 x64 home edition on it.

I am trying to install Fedora workstation 38 x86_64 with dual boot.

**What I did:**

In the fedora installation process, I mount efi partition at `/boot/efi`.

Now, in windows, I can see files in efi partition after mounting it with `mountvol B: /s`

```
B:\
│  mach_kernel
│
├─EFI
│  ├─Microsoft
│  │  ├─Boot
│  │  │  │  memtest.efi
│  │  │  │  winsipolicy.p7b
│  │  │  │  boot.stl
│  │  │  │  bootmgfw.efi
│  │  │  │  bootmgr.efi
│  │  │  │  kdnet_uart16550.dll
│  │  │  │  kdstub.dll
│  │  │  │  kd_02_10df.dll
│  │  │  │  kd_02_10ec.dll
│  │  │  │  kd_02_1137.dll
│  │  │  │  kd_02_14e4.dll
│  │  │  │  kd_02_15b3.dll
│  │  │  │  kd_02_1969.dll
│  │  │  │  kd_02_19a2.dll
│  │  │  │  kd_02_1af4.dll
│  │  │  │  BCD
│  │  │  │  kd_02_8086.dll
│  │  │  │  kd_07_1415.dll
│  │  │  │  kd_0C_8086.dll
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─bg-BG
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─CIPolicies
│  │  │  │  └─Active
│  │  │  │          {5DAC656C-21AD-4A02-AB49-649917162E70}.cip
│  │  │  │          {82443e1e-8a39-4b4a-96a8-f40ddc00b9f3}.cip
│  │  │  │          {CDD5CB55-DB68-4D71-AA38-3DF2B6473A52}.cip
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─cs-CZ
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─da-DK
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─de-DE
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─el-GR
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─en-GB
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─en-US
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─es-ES
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─es-MX
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─et-EE
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─fi-FI
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─fr-CA
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─fr-FR
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─hr-HR
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─hu-HU
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─it-IT
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─ja-JP
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─ko-KR
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─lt-LT
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─lv-LV
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─nb-NO
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─nl-NL
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─pl-PL
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─pt-BR
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─pt-PT
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─qps-ploc
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─ro-RO
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─ru-RU
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─sk-SK
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─sl-SI
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─sr-Latn-RS
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─sv-SE
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─tr-TR
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─uk-UA
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─zh-CN
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─zh-TW
│  │  │  │      bootmgfw.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      bootmgr.efi.mui
│  │  │  │      memtest.efi.mui
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  ├─Fonts
│  │  │  │      segmono_boot.ttf
│  │  │  │      segoen_slboot.ttf
│  │  │  │      segoe_slboot.ttf
│  │  │  │      chs_boot.ttf
│  │  │  │      cht_boot.ttf
│  │  │  │      jpn_boot.ttf
│  │  │  │      kor_boot.ttf
│  │  │  │      malgunn_boot.ttf
│  │  │  │      malgun_boot.ttf
│  │  │  │      meiryon_boot.ttf
│  │  │  │      meiryo_boot.ttf
│  │  │  │      msjhn_boot.ttf
│  │  │  │      msjh_boot.ttf
│  │  │  │      msyhn_boot.ttf
│  │  │  │      msyh_boot.ttf
│  │  │  │      wgl4_boot.ttf
│  │  │  │
│  │  │  └─Resources
│  │  │      │  bootres.dll
│  │  │      │
│  │  │      ├─en-US
│  │  │      │      bootres.dll.mui
│  │  │      │
│  │  │      └─zh-CN
│  │  │              bootres.dll.mui
│  │  │
│  │  └─Recovery
│  │          BCD
│  │
│  ├─Boot
│  │      BOOTIA32.EFI
│  │      fbia32.efi
│  │      fbx64.efi
│  │      LenovoBT.EFI
│  │      License.txt
│  │      ReadMe.txt
│  │      bootx64.efi
│  │
│  └─fedora
│          grub.cfg
│          BOOTIA32.CSV
│          BOOTX64.CSV
│          gcdia32.efi
│          gcdx64.efi
│          grubia32.efi
│          grubx64.efi
│          mmia32.efi
│          mmx64.efi
│          shim.efi
│          shimia32.efi
│          shimx64.efi
│
├─BOOT
│      BOOT.SDI
│
└─System
    └─Library
        └─CoreServices
                SystemVersion.plist
```

**The problem**

Before I install fedora, when I press `F12` during machine startup. I UEFI menu looks like below:

```
SamSung xxxxxx - my ssd name
```

I can boot windows normally by choosing the entry.

After I install fedora, my `F12` UEFI menu looks like below:

```
fedora
SamSung xxxxxx - my ssd name
```

And I choose the my ssd name I got something like `reset system` with blue screen and gives nothing but rebooting system.

I chose `fedora` entry, I can go into grub menu. And there is `windows boot manager` in grub menu which can boot windows normally.

**Expection**

Since UEFI is independent of operating systems. How to dual boot the multple OSs with `F12` boot menu in one disk.

I search many articles. Some articles say that multiple disks with multiple efi partitions. That will show multiple entry in `F12` boot menu.

The other say that `bootx64.efi` is the only entry of booting process. Windows will copy `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi` to bootx64.efi, while linux will copy `/EFI/fedora/shimx64.efi` to `bootx64.efi`. The former might boot other system as: bootx64.efi -> bootmgr.efi -> BCD -> shimx64.efi. The latter might boot other system as: bootx64.efi -> shimx64.efi -> grub -> bootmgr.efi.

Is it possible dual boot multiple system directly by `bootx64.efi`? How to dual boot with `F12` looks like below:

```
fedora
windows
```

Do I need edit `bootx64.efi` manully? Any helpful tools? If so, What bout secure boot? re-sign `bootx64.efi`?

Awsome reading [efi-boot-bootx64-efi-vs-efi-ubuntu-grubx64-efi-vs-boot-grub-x86-64-efi-gru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565615/efi-boot-bootx64-efi-vs-efi-ubuntu-grubx64-efi-vs-boot-grub-x86-64-efi-gru)

Comment: You should have both a Windows entry & a Fedora entry. The bootx64.efi is a drive/fallback entry not normally used. If you system is using that to boot Windows, and grub changed it to grub or shim, and Windows is hibernated or has fast start up on, then it will fail. Can you add a Windows UEFI boot entry. Post this: `sudo efibootmgr -v`. https://superuser.com/questions/1662123/how-does-uefi-decide-whoch-efi-file-to-boot-into See IV & restore Windows efi entry: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win

Comment: It could be an answer. I added a windows uefi entry by using efibootmgr. It shows in `F12` boot menu.

Comment: You can check if bootx64.efi is same size as shimx64.efi or Windows bootmgfw.efi and then make it be whichever you prefer just by copying it.

Comment: The size of bootx64.efi is same as shimx64.efi. `-rwx------. 1 root root 2026368 May 10 05:56 Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`, `-rwx------. 1 root root 946712 Jul  7  2022 fedora/shimx64.efi`, `-rwx------. 1 root root 946712 Jul  7  2022 Boot/bootx64.efi`.

Comment: I've already added the boot entry to `F12` Menu, which resolved my problem, by using `efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi" -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 1`, according to your reference https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win