# Linux Live USB doesn't boot on GIGABYTE Motherboard

Tags: linux, boot, grub, uefi, boot-loader

I have installed **Arch Linux** on a **USB** (Using `GPT` Partition Table)

I have partitioned it to 3 partitions (All of them are from type `Linux filesystem`:

1. Partition 1 which is `/boot` I have formatted as `FAT32`
2. Partition 2 which is the `SWAP` and formatted to `SWAP`
3. Partition 3 which is `/` (The root of the FS) formatted as `EXT4`

I manage to boot it from my **Dell** Laptop,
I have done it manually by adding a BOOT option and then set it to boot from `/boot/EFI/GRUB/grubx64.efi`.

However, when I connected this to my main PC (which runs **GIGABYTE** BIOS) It showed both `Legacy` and `UEFI` Versions of my USB stick automatically but when I select to boot from either it says that it can't boot from this device.

My theory is that the `BIOS` doensn't know from which `.efi` to boot, is there a way to make the BIOS point to my desired `efi` file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some EFI implementations are more picky than others. For maximum compatibility, you should use

- GPT
- an [EFI System Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) marked as such (not "Linux")
- the ESP must be at least 100 MB (no hard evidence on this one, but seems to be a general rule of thumb)
- the ESP must be formatted with FAT32 (many implementations can also read NTFS, but not all)
- on the ESP, the bootloader should be stored at [`EFI\boot\bootx64.efi`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565615/efi-boot-bootx64-efi-vs-efi-ubuntu-grubx64-efi-vs-boot-grub-x86-64-efi-gru) so the EFI can pick it up automatically

Comment: I have set everything according to your list, the only thing is that my bootloader is located in `EFI/GRUB/grubx64.efi` do I need to change that ?

Comment: Do not confuse the ESP - efi system partition which must be FAT32 with boot, esp flags and formatted FAT32 with the /boot partition which must be Linux partitioned often ext4.

Comment: Indeed, the ESP is not `/boot`. In fact, you do not need a dedicated partition for `/boot`. On Ubuntu, the ESP is usually mounted at `/boot/efi`.

Comment: Oh nice, it worked thanks!

For clarification what I did is simply `cp /boot/EFI/GRUB/grubx64.efi /boot/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` and it fixed my issue.